# Android floating action button custom behavior

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application in which I have used floating action button. Currently floating action button is aligned with collapsing toolbar layout. I want to define scroll aware behavior in such a way that when collapsing toolbar gets completely collapsed, floating action button should get scrolled  down. And when collapsing toolbar gets expanded, FAB should get to its original position. 
Here is what I wish to implement:[image]

Answer (score 0):

CoordinatorLayout extends the ability to accomplish many of the Google's Material Design scrolling effects. Currently, there are several ways provided in this framework that allow it to work without needing to write your own custom animation code. These effects include:

Sliding the Floating Action Button up and down to make space for the Snackbar.

Read the full tutorial [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)